# Maven Github repository + Artifactory

Tags: maven

I'm have a artifactory running in a server here, and my settings.xml are configured to use it has a mirror.

But, one dep I use is in a [github page](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap/maven/), and seems like artifactory doesnt get it, because it throws me "UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD blah..".

I try to add the repo in Artifactory remote repositories, click in test, and it shows me a

> Connection failed: Error 403: Forbidden

I am using the correct URL (I think): http://gwtbootstrap.github.com/maven/snapshots

Got any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Follow the repository URL.... Github 404 page :-( That would explain why it's not working

Comment: its because it isnt a github page... but if I add to pom.xml and make install it works... it just dont work under arctifactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the URL should be:

- https://github.com/gwtbootstrap/maven/tree/gh-pages/snapshots